# RSA Signature is different generated from rsa module and m2crypto

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, rsa, digital-signature, m2crypto

I am migrating a service from Python 2.7 to Python 3.5 which communicated with another service using RSA encryption/decryption.

---

Python(v2.7) m2crypto(0.25.1) < Correct Signature >

```
key = M2Crypto.RSA.load_key(private_key)
digest = hashlib.sha1(bytes(cipher_text, encoding="UTF-8")).hexdigest()
signature = hexlify(key.private_encrypt(digest, M2Crypto.RSA.pkcs1_padding))
```

---

Python(v3.5) rsa(v3.4.2)

```
pri_key = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(private_key)
signature = hexlify(rsa.sign(cipher_text.encode(), pri_key, "SHA-1"))
```

Signature produced by above codes are different. What is the difference between these packages?

Answer (score 0):

You are executing different cryptographic operations. **encrypt with private key != digital signature**

```
signature = hexlify(key.private_encrypt(digest, M2Crypto.RSA.pkcs1_padding))
```

and

```
signature = hexlify(rsa.sign(cipher_text.encode(), pri_key, "SHA-1"))
```

A digital signature with PCKS#1 v1.5 makes a RSA encryption on digest algorithm identifier and the digest of the message encoded in ASN.1

```
signature = 
    RSA_Encryption( 
      ASN.1(DigestAlgorithmIdentifier  + SHA1(message) ))
```

While encryption does not include the digest algorithm identifier

Seems Python `key.private_encrypt` is a wrapper on openssl [RSA_private_encrypt](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:RSA_private_encrypt(3)) Take a look to the warning about the`pkcs1_padding` you are using

> **RSA_PKCS1_PADDING**
>
> PKCS #1 v1.5 padding. This function does not handle the **algorithmIdentifier** specified in PKCS #1. When generating or verifying PKCS #1 signatures, `RSA_sign(3)` and `RSA_verify(3)` should be used.

You should use `sign` and not `private_encrypt` for digital signatures. But if you want encryption to hide the content of the message, you should use encryption with the public key, not the private.

Comment: But what if the second service accepts signature generated from m2crypto code, What should I do in that case?

Comment: If you own this service, I suggest you modify it accordingly. If it is not possible, I suppose you have no choice but to continue using `private_encrypt`

Comment: Alternative option is to help me finish https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/merge_requests/65 and you don't have to port out of M2Crypto ;). However, I am working right now on the support for OpenSSL 1.1.0, so the major rebase of that branch is to be expected.

Comment: @infiQuanta is my answer acceptable, do you need any further clarification?